# What is the java Vector.element() C# equivalent

Tags: c#, java

Here is the java code i incompletely tried to translate

```
    static Enumeration enumerate()
    {
    Vector list = new Vector();
    Enumeration e = cache.keys();
    while (e.hasMoreElements())
    {
         Vector v = (Vector) cache.get(e.nextElement());
         for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
         {
         list.addElement(v.elementAt(i));
         }
    }
   return list.elements();
     }
```

This is the C# translation but not complete

```
    public static IEnumerable<Http> enumurate()
    {
        List<Http> list = new List<Http>();
        IEnumerator e = cache.Keys.GetEnumerator();
        while (e.MoveNext())/*While e has more element*/
        {
            var vector = (List<Http>)cache[e.Current];
            for (int i = 0; i < vector.Count; i++)
            {
                list.Add(vector.ElementAt<Http>(i));
            }
        }
        return //Something missing!!
    }
```

Any help please !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C# `List<Http>` implements `IEnumerable<Http>` so you can simply return your list:

```
return list;
```

To convert the code to C# even more, you could just skip the adding of elements to the list and yield results directly:

```
public static IEnumerable<Http> enumerate()
{
    IEnumerator e = cache.Keys.GetEnumerator();
    while (e.MoveNext())/*While e has more element*/
    {
        var vector = (List<Http>)cache[e.Current];
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return vector.ElementAt<Http>(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can avoid using enumerators directly and make the code even more readable:

```
public static IEnumerable<Http> enumerate()
{
    foreach (var key in cache.Keys)
    {
        foreach (var http in (List<Http>)cache[key])
        {
            yield return http;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return the local `list`. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can use LINQ to simplify your code:

```
public static IEnumerable<Http> enumerate()
{ return cache.Keys.SelectMany(key => (List<Http>)cache[key]); }
```

Assuming `cache` is declared as `Dictionary<..., List<Http>>` you can avoid key lookup by using the `Values` property:

```
public static IEnumerable<Http> enumerate()
{ return cache.Values.SelectMany(list => list); }
```

One important difference between the above and the code that you have now is that the above is not evaluated until you actually try to iterate through the returned collection. If you want to evaluate results immediately, you can add a call to `.ToList()`. This is equivalent to your original code:

```
public static IEnumerable<Http> enumerate()
{ return cache.Keys.SelectMany(key => (List<Http>)cache[key]).ToList(); }
```